# Декораторы сообщений с неизвестными элементами и парсинг как во фреймворке Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Мне была поставлена задача сделать обработку сообщений с помощью декораторов. Задача была выполнена так:

---

*Класс декораторов выглядел так:*

```py
class Events:
    _messages_func = dict()
    _undefined_messages_func = (
        lambda: print('Добавьте в код on_undefined декоратор')
    )

    def on_message(text: str):
        def decorator(func):
            self._messages_func[text] = func
            return func
        return decorator

    def on_undefined():
        def decorator(func):
            self._undefined_messages_func = func
            return func
        return decorator
```

---

*Класс самого "бота" выглядел так:*

```py
class Bot(Events):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # Далее была связь с API и так далее, но это не меняет условия задачи

    def process_message(text: str):
        if text in self._messages_func:
            self._messages_func[text]()
        else:
            self._undefined_messages_func()
```

---

Далее я использовал это так:

```py
bot = Bot()

@bot.on_message('привет')
def my_function():
    print('Мне написали привет!')


message = input('Введи сообщение >>')
bot.process_message(message)
```

---

Все работало прекрасно, до тех пор пока я не получил задание добавить в on_message элементы как в route во flask. То есть там можно в сам декоратор route написать:
`@app.route('/<my_var>')`
и my_var вернется в функцию как именованный аргумент

Например такой декоратор:

```py
@bot.on_message('страница <page>')
def my_function(page):
    print(f'Открываю страницу {page}')
```

При процессинге сообщения "страница 10", будет выведено "Открываю страницу 10"
Конечно, это можно просто реализовать с помощью split по пробелам, но так же мне хотелось бы поддерживать например такие штуки как:
`Я родился 07.08.2019`

**Я пытался реализовать это с помощью регулярных выражений и в течении этого времени чуть не сошел с ума, есть ли способ лучше и как это вообще возможно реализовать?**

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Распарсить `'страница <page>'`? Или в передаче именованного параметра в декораторе?

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov на данный момент не только о парсинге, а больше о том, как мне проверить соответствует ли введенное сообщение со значениями одному из значений в _messages_func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начать можно с этого

```py
import re

def to_regex(text, escape={ord(x): '\\' + x for x in r'\.*+?()[]|^$'}):
    pattern = re.sub('(<.*?>)',  r'(?P\1.*)', text.translate(escape))
    return re.compile(pattern)
```

А дальше дело техники

```py
>>> to_regex('страница <page>').match('страница 10').groupdict()
{'page': '10'}
>>> to_regex('Меня зовут <name>.').match('Меня зовут Иван Иванович.').groupdict()
{'name': 'Иван Иванович'}
>>> to_regex('<a> + <b> = <c>').match('11 + 4 = 15').groupdict()
{'a': '11', 'b': '4', 'c': '15'}
```

Текст, само собой, должен совпадать с шаблоном очень точно. Для нечеткого сравнения понадобится куда более сложный алгоритм.

Comment: Спасибо за решение парсинга строк, но свой код я расписал еще для того чтобы узнать решение передачи и проверки. Например, как мне проверить, что введенное сообщение соответствует одному из regexов в _messages_func

Comment: Придется в цикле сопоставить текст `text` с каждым ключом `key` из `_messages_func`, (которые теперь будут скомпилированными регулярными выражениями, а не строками). И при первом совпадении (`key.match(text) is not None`) вызвать соответствующую ключу функцию с аргументом `key.match(text).groupdict()`

Comment: @extern Это конечно печально, что нет решения быстрее, еще до обращения сюда, я делал примерно так же, но думал что здесь мне дадут решение профессиональней. Спасибо за ваш вердикт

Comment: Разумеется, это не образец эффективности, скорее простоты и доступности. Миллион сравнений в секунду такой метод вполне способен обеспечить. Если этого недостаточно - придется либо писать собственный эффективный алгоритм сопоставления с образцом, либо искать готовую реализацию. В конце концов подсмотреть, как это сделано во flask.

Answer (score 0):

Так это вопрос не про декораторы, а про парсинг строки?

Такой вариант подойдет:

```
import re
page = 13
a = 'страница <page>'
m = re.match(r'(.*?) <(.+)>', a)
print("{} {}".format(m.group(1), eval(m.group(2))))
```

> страница 13

либо через globals с тем же результатом:

```
print("{} {}".format(m.group(1), globals()[m.group(2)]))
```

**НО!**

*eval* - это дыра в безопасности. мало ли, что передадут в декоратор. а с *globals* вам нужно точно определяться с областью видимости переменных.

Comment: Спасибо за решение парсинга строк, но свой код я расписал еще для того чтобы узнать решение передачи и проверки. Например, как мне проверить, что введенное сообщение соответствует одному из regexов в _messages_func